# Problem with CSASPNETFacebookApp: no redirect_uri

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Hi 
the sample works on my local computer but it does not on the iis 7. 
It seems, that there is no redirect_uri set. The error message:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Die Anwendungseinstellungen erlauben die angegebene URL nicht.

This means: redirect_uri is not allowed by the app settings. 
It seems to be empty. 
Thanks for Help

Comment: When do you see this error? When authenticating the user?

Comment: Yes, by calling if (!auth.IsAuthorized()). Enabling (ISAPI and CGI Restricions) didn't help. It is on II7, 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't set the CanvasURL on Facebook for your App? You can copy it from Web.config.